# Get color of shadow

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have scene with ground and directional light. My ground is sin() function and light makes some parts of ground brighter, some darker. How can I get exact color of ground part using x,y,z coordinates?

I can get ground object using `scene.getChildByName("ground")`, but where can I find color of each vertex?
[image: scene]

Here is jsFiddle of my question: http://jsfiddle.net/zk1vb81x/3/

Comment: the color of a specific pixel is calculated in the shader. the color of the shadow as well. as far as i know the shader gets sent to the graphics card which calculates the color and puts it on the screen. it doesnt return values. a dirty solution would be to use `canvas.getImageData`to get the pixel color.

Comment: would it be possible to create another shader that would process after calculations and return colors?

Comment: im sorry for the delayed reply. considering bitcoin mining is often done via the graphics card, it must be possible for the graphics card to be able to return values, how to accomplish that i wouldnt know, i know very little GLSL.